# SELECT columns FROM t1, join with COUNT of columnX in t2, COUNT of columnY in t3

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine data from 3 tables as follows :

```
    SELECT u.USER_ID,u.USERNAME,u.FIRST_NAME,u.LAST_NAME,u.ISACTIVE, 
    u.ISADMIN, COUNT(m.PURCHASED_ID) AS MOVIES_PURCHASED, 
    COUNT(r.RENTED_ID) AS MOVIES_RENTED

    FROM TBL_USERS AS u 
    LEFT JOIN TBL_MOVIE_PURCHASED AS m 
    ON u.USER_ID = m.USER_ID 

    LEFT JOIN TBL_RENTED_MOVIES AS r 
    ON u.USER_ID = r.USER_ID 

    GROUP BY u.USER_ID,u.USERNAME,u.FIRST_NAME,u.LAST_NAME,u.ISACTIVE,u.ISADMIN
    ORDER BY MOVIES_PURCHASED, MOVIES_RENTED;
```

The tables have the following columns :

```
TBL_USERS : 
USER_ID, USERNAME, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ISACTIVE, ISADMIN

TBL_MOVIE_PURCHASED :
USER_ID, MOVIE_ID, PURCHASE_ID, PURCHASED_ON (purchase ID is unique)

TBL_RENTED_MOVIES : 
USER_ID, MOVIE_ID, RENTED_ID, RENTED_ON (rented ID is unique )
```

I am trying to display :

```
1.  all contents of TBL_USERS 
2.  the count of the rented movies for every user from TBL_RENTED_MOVIES,
3.  the count of the purchased movies for every user from TBL_MOVIES_PURCHASED.
4.  ORDER BY the results based on both COUNTS.
```

**If say user1 has rented 5 movies and purchased 10 movies, then the query is supposed to return :**

```
(MOVIES_PURCHASED, MOVIES_RENTED) = (5,10).
```

Instead, the query returns 5*10 = 50 for both columns :

```
(MOVIES_PURCHASED, MOVIES_RENTED) = (50,50)
```

I know I have gone wrong in joining the results. I tried using UNION to combine results as well but didnt work. Any ideas?

Hence, The output should Ideally be :

```
USER_ID, USERNAME, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ISACTIVE, ISADMIN, MOVIES_PURCHASED, MOVIES-RENTED :
1, user1, userFirst, userLast, Active, NotAdmin, 5, 10
```

. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Here is the sqlfiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d44a2/2/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple DISTINCT keyword for m.PURCHASE_ID and r.RENTED_ID solves the problem :

the query that worked is :

```
SELECT u.USER_ID,u.USERNAME,u.FIRST_NAME,u.LAST_NAME,u.ISACTIVE, u.ISADMIN, COUNT(DISTINCT m.PURCHASED_ID) AS MOVIES_PURCHASED, COUNT(DISTINCT r.RENTED_ID) AS MOVIES_RENTED, 
(COUNT(DISTINCT m.PURCHASED_ID) + COUNT(DISTINCT r.RENTED_ID)) AS MAX_ACTIVITY
FROM TBL_USERS AS u 
LEFT JOIN TBL_MOVIE_PURCHASED AS m 
ON u.USER_ID = m.USER_ID 
LEFT JOIN TBL_RENTED_MOVIES AS r 
ON u.USER_ID = r.USER_ID 
GROUP BY u.USER_ID,u.USERNAME,u.FIRST_NAME,u.LAST_NAME,u.ISACTIVE,u.ISADMIN
ORDER BY MAX_ACTIVITY DESC;
```

I added an extra MAX_ACTIVITY column and ordered the results by max_activity.

the link to an example for creating multiple tables, performing left joins on them, counting values for columns, ordering and grouping them and avoiding redundant data from being displayed while performing the joins :

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d44a2/2/0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way...

```
CREATE table USERS(USER_ID integer primary key, 
                       USERNAME varchar(50), FIRST_NAME varchar(50),
                       LAST_NAME varchar(50), ISACTIVE VARCHAR(10)
                       DEFAULT '0',
                       ISADMIN VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '0');

CREATE table MOVIES_PURCHASED(PURCHASE_ID integer primary key, 
                               USER_ID integer,
                               FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID), 
                               PURCHASED_ON VARCHAR(50));

CREATE table MOVIES_RENTED(RENTED_ID integer primary key, 
                               USER_ID integer,
                               FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID), 
                               RENTED_ON VARCHAR(50));





INSERT INTO USERS (USER_ID, USERNAME, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ISACTIVE, ISADMIN)
VALUES
(1, 'user1', 'user1FN', 'user1LN', '1', '0'),
(2, 'user2', 'user2FN', 'user2LN', '1', '0'),
(3, 'user3', 'user3FN', 'user3LN', '1', '0'),
(4, 'user4', 'user4FN', 'user4LN', '1', '0'),
(5, 'user5', 'user5FN', 'user5LN', '1', '0');


insert into MOVIES_RENTED  (RENTED_ID, USER_ID, RENTED_ON) 
values 
(1, 5 ,'2014-07-05'),
(2, 4 ,'2014-07-05'),
(3, 5 ,'2014-07-05'),
(4, 4 ,'2014-07-05'),
(5, 5 ,'2014-07-05'),
(6, 5 ,'2014-07-05'),
(7, 3 ,'2014-07-05'),
(8, 2 ,'2014-07-05'),
(9, 2 ,'2014-07-05'),
(10, 1 ,'2014-07-05');


insert into MOVIES_PURCHASED  (PURCHASE_ID, USER_ID, PURCHASED_ON) 
values 
(1, 1 ,'2014-07-05'),
(2, 3 ,'2014-07-05'),
(3, 3 ,'2014-07-05'),
(4, 3 ,'2014-07-05'),
(5, 4 ,'2014-07-05'),
(6, 4 ,'2014-07-05'),
(7, 5 ,'2014-07-05'),
(8, 5 ,'2014-07-05'),
(9, 1 ,'2014-07-05'),
(10, 2 ,'2014-07-05'),
(11, 2 ,'2014-07-05'),
(12, 2 ,'2014-07-05');

SELECT u.*
     , SUM(x.source = 'rented') rented
     , SUM(x.source = 'purchased') purchased
     , COUNT(x.source) total
  FROM users u
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT 'rented' source, user_id FROM movies_rented
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'purchased', user_id FROM movies_purchased
     ) x
    ON x.user_id = u.user_id
 GROUP
    BY user_id
 ORDER 
    BY total DESC;

USER_ID     USERNAME        FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME       ISACTIVE  ISADMIN   RENTED    PURCHASED TOTAL
5           user5           user5FN    user5LN         1         0         4         2         6
2           user2           user2FN    user2LN         1         0         2         3         5
4           user4           user4FN    user4LN         1         0         2         2         4
3           user3           user3FN    user3LN         1         0         1         3         4
1           user1           user1FN    user1LN         1         0         1         2         3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b3c8/10

Comment: I tried your query and worked like magic. Thanks for the help :)